# ASP.NET MVC - Contained User Controls

Tags: asp.net-mvc, viewusercontrol

I want to be able to create ViewUserControls with their own controllers so all the logic is contained completely.  Right now, I have to wire up the ViewUserControls with the main controller and if I wanted to use these viewUserControls elsewhere, I would have to wire them up again.  Is it possible to do what I'm hoping for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for are subcontrollers. There's been talk they will come in ASP.NET MVC 2 but there is no more news on that yet.

Right now you could check out [MVC Contrib](http://www.codeplex.com/MVCContrib) project. It has support for subcontrollers.

[MvcContrib - now with SubController support for ASP.NET MVC](http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/mvccontrib-now-with-subcontroller-support/)